# Pre-Filter jQuery DataTables AJAX result based on specific column value

Tags: jquery, ajax, filter, datatables

I have a JSON file containing all the data, so basically it's the data for 10 different tables in one file.
Now, when I'm on a certain page (A) I only wish to output the data from the file where the value of column[0] (my identifier sits in the first column) is "A".

I'm really not sure what to put where:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax": '../ajax/data/arrays.txt'
} );
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

**Got it working.**

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "ajax": {
        "url": "../ajax/data/arrays.txt",
        "dataSrc": function(json) {
            let data = json.data;
            let filter = data.filter(function(value, index, arr){
                return value[0] === 'A';
            });
            return filter;
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of embedding your answer in the body of the question, you are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) by writing an actual answer. You may also want to [up-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) the existing answer if you found it useful - that is the preferred way of saying "thank you" instead of leaving a "thank you" comment.

Comment: Be aware that this type of question has been asked - and answered  - [many times already](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdatatables%5D+pre+filter) on SO, so please ensure you research your question before asking it. There is a good chance that an existing answer would have given you a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dataSrc` option of `ajax` configuration:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax": {
        url: '../ajax/data/arrays.txt', 
        dataSrc: function(json) {
            // run logic on json to select only your desired rows
            return result;
       } 
});
```

Comment: thanks, could you please elaborate...since I'm very new to JS/jquery

Comment: I'd suggest to try your own solutions looking at the official DataTables docs & examples (both very well written). It's by far the best and fastest way to learn new stuff ;)

Comment: thanks to your hint i got it working...

Comment: You're welcome @Marc. It's a good habit to upvote answers that solve your problem ;)